# check value in column is list type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns `field` and `value`. I am performing some checks on each field's value. For `field a` I need to check its corresponding value is always `list` type and storing its result in `status` column

Below is code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import is_list_like

data = {
    "field": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "value": [[1, "na", -99], 20, 80],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print("Initial DF")
print(f"{df=}")

condlist = [df["field"] == "a", df["field"] == "b", df["field"] == "c"]

choicelist = [
    df["value"].apply(is_list_like).any(),
    df["value"].isin([10, 20, 30, 40]),
    df["value"].between(50, 100),
]

df["status"] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, False)

print("After check DF")
print(f"{df=}")
```

But getting error as

```
 df["value"].between(50, 100),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "pandas/_libs/ops.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform all non-numeric values in `df["value"]` to `None` by trying to apply `pd.to_numeric` to the column. That way `between` won't throw an error and status will be updated correctly.

```
choicelist = [
    df["value"].apply(is_list_like).any(),
    df["value"].isin([10, 20, 30, 40]),
    pd.to_numeric(df["value"], errors='coerce').between(50, 100),
]
```

However, it may be worth considering rethinking the data structure, if possible - and store only one data type per column.

Comment: Hi Maria, Thanks. Earlier all were scalar either `int` or `str`. Recently new field got added which is of `list` type. Your solution is working fine with scalar(int, str) and also including list. I have maximum `10` rows having value type that can be int or str or list. Is it ok to keep it this way if there is no side effect? or may be we can club `scalar` values (int and str) in one group and other group for list if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your snippet as follow :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.types import is_list_like

data = {
    "field": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "value": [[1, "na", -99], 20, 80],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

condlist = [df["field"] == "a", df["field"] == "b", df["field"] == "c"]

def apply_between(element, lower, upper):
    if isinstance(element, (int, float)):
        return lower <= element <= upper
    return element

choicelist = [
    df["value"].apply(is_list_like).any(),
    df["value"].isin([10, 20, 30, 40]),
    df["value"].apply(lambda x: apply_between(x, 50, 100))
]

df["status"] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, False)

print("After check DF")
print(f"{df=}")
```

```
After check DF
df=  field         value status
0     a  [1, na, -99]   True
1     b            20   True
2     c            80   True
```

Comment: Hi Laurent, Thanks. This looks better than my thought to club scalar values in one group and list type in other by reducing the code.